# how to add URL a parameter to the request in iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I need to add a parameter to the each URL loaded in the iframe: if someone tries to open https://www.google.ru I have to load page with parameter: https://www.google.ru/?noredirect=true. Have no idea how to resolve this(

Thanks.

Comment: How do you load URL in iframe?

Comment: I have just the iframe with default src= "/", user can click any link on the page.